# Imprimir array de Curl

Tags: php, libcurl

Faço um Curl no php em uma url e ele me retorna:

```
array(2) { ["tip"]=> int(1) ["msg"]=> string(3) "826" }
```

Quero pegar so o numero 826 e trabalhar om ele em php.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nesse caso, fará:

```
echo $array_retornado['msg']; // 826
```

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado amigo!!!

Comment: de nada @Thiago